# build error in visual studio 2017

Tags: c

I try to implement the approximation of sin(x) with the code below, but the compiler reports building error when I run the program. I've checked but not sure what's wrong with it, maybe overloading. Thanks a lot for your help!

```
/*Approximate sinx*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
float sin(float);
float factor(int);
float times(float, int);

int main()
{
    float x;
    scanf_s("%f", &x);
    printf("%f", sin(x));
    system("cease");
    return 0;
}

float factor(int x)
{
    float factor=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        factor *= i;
    }
    return factor;
}

float times(float x, int y)
{
    float times=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        times *= x;
    }
    return times;
}

float sin(float x)
{
    float sinx=0;
    int t = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        sinx +=t* times(x, 2*i-1) / factor(2*i-1);
        t *= -1;
    }

    return sinx;
}
```

And the output is as below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Testor, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>d:\ccode\testor\testor\source.cpp(6): error C2382: 'sin': redefinition; different exception specifications
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\cmath(281): note: see declaration of 'sin'
1>d:\ccode\testor\testor\source.cpp(14): error C2264: 'sin': error in function definition or declaration; function not called
1>d:\ccode\testor\testor\source.cpp(14): warning C4473: 'printf' : not enough arguments passed for format string
1>d:\ccode\testor\testor\source.cpp(14): note: placeholders and their parameters expect 1 variadic arguments, but 0 were provided
1>d:\ccode\testor\testor\source.cpp(14): note: the missing variadic argument 1 is required by format string '%f'
1>Done building project "Testor.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You need to include the errors, we aren't going to sift through that without any idea where to look.

Comment: Change `sin` to another name. It occurs in `cmath`. As per error message

Comment: There's a `sin` function declared in the [`<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) header file.  Just as the error message tells you. You *did* read it? And I suggest you use the standard [`std::sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) function instead of making your own.

Comment: And why are you using `printf` in C++ code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you are trying to use a name that already exist in the standard library, give your sinx a different name (or put it in a namespace). The printf error is due to the problems the compiler had with the sinx call.